# overlay above markers that won't allow clicking the markers beneath it , google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've added an OverlayView to the map. I have a lot of different markers on map. 
I allow clicking drawn objects on the canvas, but i don't want to allow clicking any shape / marker on the map while the overlay object's enabled property it true.

How can i do that? without keeping track of ALL the markers/ shapes/ (could be a lot!) and then running on each of them , removing the click listener 
and at the end adding it..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable `overlayEnabled` and update it every time you enable/disable the overlay. Then in your click listeners, check that variable before performing any action.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
    if(overlayEnabled) {
        // perform action
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

Comment: That's what i'm trying to avoid. Adding a check to all markers. I want it to be agnostic to other objects, as it should be.

The other way around would be to keep all visible markers in array and loop through them, while the overlay is visible and invoke the click event and when the overlay is hidden to revoke it, but again, i want to avoid doing this.

Question is, if i can put the overlay ABOVE the markers overlay so no click to them will be possible or some other way of doing this..

Comment: try adding your OverlayView object at a higher level on the DOM in your onAdd(). `this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild()`

Comment: Nope, i tried that before (with all of them actually). Reason is: i need to handle mouse events , for the canvas but not for the markers/polygons/etc.. , this causes 2 things: have an overlay that can't handle DOM or have one that can (thus also triggers markers/polygons/etc..) ... :/